# Using rsync when files on one end are all lowercase

Tags: windows, linux, rsync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make rsync case insensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/256751/make-rsync-case-insensitive)

I want to rsync a lot of files from a Windows box to a Linux server.

The problem is, the files on Windows are all mixed case, and the files on the linux server need to be all lowercase.

One solution is to have a script that rsyncs to a different directory on the server, copy the files into the main directory, and then convert them all to lowercase. I'd rather find a more elegant solution, though.

I'd prefer a command line application, but I'd be willing to go with a GUI application if that's the best option.

Comment: Linux files *need to be* lowercase, or already are? Is this a sync problem or a copy-and-rename one?

Comment: Linux files _need_ to be lowercase **and** already are.

Right now I just rsync them to a directory, copy them into the main directory, and then convert to lowercase. I'd like a way to do it with just one rsync command, though.